# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render, propTypes, displayName, post, Naked, options, useStyles})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have this error on my React website: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render, propTypes, displayName, post, Naked, options, useStyles}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

My code is here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import Post from '../components/Post';

export class Home extends Component {
    state = {
        posts: null
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/posts')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ posts: res.data })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    render() {
        let recentPostsMarkup = this.state.posts ? (
            this.state.posts.map(singlePost => <Post post={singlePost} />)
        ) : <p>Loading...</p>
        return (
            <Grid container /*spacing={16}*/>
                <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
                    {recentPostsMarkup}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                    <p>Profile...</p>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

This one below is the class component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import Link from 'react-router-dom/Link';

// MUI cards
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
// Typography
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const styles = {
    card: {
        display: 'flex',
    }
}

class Post extends Component {
    render() {
        const { classes, post : {
            body,
            userImage,
            createdAt,
            userHandle,
            postId,
            likeCount,
            commentCount
        } } = this.props;

        return (
            <Card>
                <CardMedia
                    image={userImage}
                    title="Profile img"
                    color="primary" />
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography
                        variant="h5" component={Link} to={`/users/${userHandle}`}>{userHandle}</Typography>
                    <Typography
                        variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{createdAt}</Typography>
                    <Typography
                        variant="body1">{body}</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(Post)
```

I use firebase to store all the data and all the fields are strings.

Comment: so I'm assuming it's the {recentPostsMarkup} that's causing the issue. I'd try these things to see what they do: remove {recentPostsMarkup} altogther, try it when it's set to `<p>`, and try it when it's set to `posts.map` independently.

Comment: Can you share Post component?

Comment: @TKoL It gives me that error when instead of having a <p> Component I use <Post post={post} />

Comment: @zhuber I edit the question with the Page's code

Comment: I found the error myself. Thanks for the help.